# How to reference and call a method from a non-attached script in Unity's edit-mode?"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a custom package in Unity. I have an object (VegetationManager), and this object also has the script 'vegetationManager'. Additionally, there's an editor that adds a button. When this button is clicked, a function in the VegetationManager is invoked. This function is supposed to call a function in another script (vegetationGenerator). The script 'vegetationGenerator' doesn't have its own game object. How can I reference the second script in the first one so that I can call it? When I use "public VegetationGenerator vegetationGenerator", I cannot drag and drop the script there. The tool is meant to be used exclusively in edit-mode.

These are the scripts I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Splines;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Vegetation.Editor.Scripts
{
    public class VegetationPlacementManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject PlantPrefab_01;
        public GameObject PlantPrefab_02;
        public GameObject PlantPrefab_03;

        public GameObject Vegetation;
        public GameObject MeshObject;

        public Terrain Terrain;
        public SplineContainer Spline;
        public int NumberOfTrees = 0;

        public VegetationGenerator vegetationGenerator;
        public BoundingBoxManager boundingBoxManager;

        public void CreateVegetation()
        {
            vegetationGenerator.GenerateVegetation();

        }

        public void DeleteAllVegetation()
        {
            vegetationGenerator.DeleteAllVegetation();
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Vegetation.Editor.Scripts
{
    public class VegetationGenerator : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private List<GameObject> _vegetationList = new List<GameObject>();

        public void GenerateVegetation()
        {

        }

        public void DeleteAllVegetation()
        {
            foreach (GameObject plant in _vegetationList)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(plant);
            }

            Debug.Log(_vegetationList.Count + " Plants deleted");

            _vegetationList.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reference the second script without a game object, without static, exclusively in edit-mode, so that I can call the function?"

Comment: `The script 'vegetationGenerator' doesn't have its own game object.`  ... why is it a `MonoBehaviour` then? Where do you get your instance from? Sounds like it could be a `static` class? or the `VegetationPlacementManager` can simply hold its own instance `private VegetationGenerator vegetationGenerator = new ();` ... a bit unclear where exactly this is going ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the `VegetationGenerator` script a static class. That way, you won't need to attach the script to any game object, but you can still call the functions in it.

Here's an example of what the `VegetationGenerator` script might look like as a static class, just based on what I see in your `VegetationPlacementManager` script

```cs
    [ExecuteInEditMode] // This allows the script to be used in edit mode
    public static class VegetationGenerator
    {
         GenerateVegetation()
         {
              // Write whatever code you use to generate vegetation here
         }

         DeleteAllVegetation
         {
              // Write whatever code you use to generate vegetation here
         }
    }
```

Then, in your `VegetationPlacementManager` script, you don't need to make a public reference to the `VegetationGenerator`. Instead, you can just access its variables and functions using the static class's name, followed by the function or variable name like this: `VegetationGenerator.GenerateVegetation();`

So in your VegetationPlacementManager functions, you can write this instead

```cs
    public void GenerateVegetation()
        {
             VegetationGenerator.GenerateVegetation();
        }
    public void DeleteAllVegetation()
        {
            VegetationGenerator.DeleteAllVegetation();
        }
```